# Jupyter server not working while using WSL2 and conda env

Tags: visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook, jupyter, conda, wsl-2

Whenever I try to run a jupyter notebook via WSL2 , I seem to be unable to connect to a kernel when running a VSCODE. The Vscode is running in Ubuntu, but I cannot connect to the remote jupyter server. I was able to do so for the last couple of months but suddenly, without me recalling channging anything, this process stopped working.

After typing 'jupyter notebook' in the terminal, I geth the following error in red, which (I think?) I received before and the jupyter was working nonetheless. However what's different is the 'forbidden' message. (see picture below)

My usual process was in WSL: conda activate env -> jupyter notebook > open another terminal -> conda activate env -> code . -> (vscode opens up running in wsl) -> copy paste one of the URLS to jupyter server -> viola it's working.

Thank you

[image]

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It seems simply restarting the computer somehow solved the issue, interesting.